# Facebook OpenID for Yahoo not working

Tags: facebook

Thought it's going to be fixed sooner but it's been a month now and i can't login to facebook using my yahoo account.

I've been getting this error:

```
 Sorry, something went wrong.

 We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.
```

Gmail works fine but yahoo isn't really working. not sure if it's yahoo OPENID or Facebook

Anyone have a fix with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 0):

Yes Im having this problem too, I was accustomed on just logging in using my yahoo so that I only have a single sign on property for all social accounts. But the openid for yahoo on facebook stops working